# Aspx pages in IIS 5.1 on WinXP

Tags: asp.net, iis, aspnet-regiis.exe

I've been developing in VS 2005 w .Net 2.0.

I want to test this website from an outside local so am trying to set up IIS.

Apparently only IIS 5.1 is compatible with XP, but by defualt it only hosts .asp (not aspx)
pages.

Is there a way to host aspx pages w .Net 2.0 in IIS5.1?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install the .net 2.0 framework onto the computer with IIS5.1 in order to install the ISAPI filter IIS needs to run .net pages.  From there, you can then install the ASP.Net scripts to the site by using the aspnet_regiis.exe utility located in the framework's installation folder.

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution would be to try installing [Microsoft Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/).

It will install required libraries and servers, perform basic configuration (like running aspnet_regiis, etc.), all in several clicks.

It's really helpful to get up to speed in as little time as possible.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is for .Net 2.0 to be installed and registered on the machine.

Now, it sounds like you already had .Net 2.0 installed on this computer when you added IIS.  The thing is that IIS for XP predates .Net, and so it doesn't know to look for or register .Net when on installation.  That means you need to register it manually.

Look for the [aspnet_regiis.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(VS.80).aspx) file and run it with the `-i` option, and you should be good.